# Problema ao declarar variáveis para cálculo de média no Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n1 = input("informe sua nota do 1º Bimestre ")
n2 = input("informe sua nota do 2º Bimestre ")
n3 = input("informe sua nota do 3º Bimestre ")
n4 = input("informe sua nota do 4º Bimestre ")
media = float((n1 + n2 + n3 + n4)) / int(4)
print("A média é",media)

informe sua nota do 1º Bimestre 2
informe sua nota do 2º Bimestre 2
informe sua nota do 3º Bimestre 2
informe sua nota do 4º Bimestre 2
A média é 555.5
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No Python 2, [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) retorna um objeto Python interpretado segundo a sintaxe dessa linguagem (i.e. se você digita "2", ele retorna o número `2`). No Python 3, [ele simplesmente retorna uma string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) (o mesmo que o [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) do Python 2, se não me engano).

Dessa forma, ao somar os valores de `n1` a `n4` você na verdade está fazendo uma concatenação de strings, e não uma soma de números:

```
float ((n1 + n2 + n3 + n4)) / int(4)
= float('2' + '2' + '2' + '2') / 4
= float('2222') / 4
= 2222/4
= 555.5
```

Para chegar ao resultado que quer, converta cada variável individual a um número:

```
n1 = float( input ("informe sua nota do 1º Bimestre ") )
n2 = float( input ("informe sua nota do 2º Bimestre ") )
n3 = float( input ("informe sua nota do 3º Bimestre ") )
n4 = float( input ("informe sua nota do 4º Bimestre ") )
media = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4) / 4
```